# How should I handle authentication when my mobile apps report their device tokens to my server?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that runs across iOS and Android. I'm working to add push notifications to that app.

At a very high level, devices register with the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) or Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) and receive a token. They then hand that token back to the server that's in charge of sending notifications. That server, when it wants to, sends a notification to APNS or GCM and says "send this notification to the devices with these tokens".

So, my apps need to be able to securely send their tokens to my server, and delete those tokens from the server when the user no longer wants to receive notifications. It's very easy to add a simple CRUD page on the server side which handles `?create=<token>`, `?delete=<token>`, etc.

<s>But what happens when someone goes to my server and starts spamming random values for `?delete=<token>` — it seems like they'd be able to just delete random device tokens at will?</s>

I've thought about the "delete" case a bit more, and I think it should be easy: the app can just send along a generated public decryption key with the initial “create this token” request. That key can be stored against the token. When the app wants to delete, it can send along the encrypted copy of the token, and the server can match the token against the decrypted copy, verifying that the app must possess the stored public keys matching private encryption key (which is a secret known only to the app).

What happens when someone starts spamming random values for `?create=<token>` — do they get to just fill up my database table with fake device tokens?

I can't see an easy answer — rate limiting "create" requests from any single IP address seems to be about the best we can do without registration involved. That obviously isn't going to help us against any distributed attack.

Ideally I'd like to enable push notifications by default / without the user having to "register" or anything like that. My first thought is that each device token should be tied to a known canonical Apple ID or Google account — but how do I stop users from falsifying those? Do devices come with a certificate that I can get an authoritative public key for (in which case each device can just get a row tied to its public key)? What's the best way for me to implement authentication here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the problem for android can be found [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html). In brief it can be summarised as

> You use the GoogleAuthUtil class, available through Google Play
>   services, to retrieve a string called an “ID Token”. You send the
>   token to your back end and your back end can use it to quickly and
>   cheaply verify which app sent it and who was using the app.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about GoogleAuthUtil - I wasn't previously aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good questions here. :)

Let me try to break it down.

**General thoughts**

- I don't think it's good idea to mix Android and iOS here. High level push notification architecture is similar between them, but that's about it.
- Tokens are long (as I remember iOS token is uuid). So, there is no way to guess it by just randomly trying different values. So, I would say `?delete=<token>` case is non existent.
- The case of `?create=<token>` is more realistic. First of all, somebody can bring your server to knees, registering millions of tokens. Also, if you are sending some sensitive information via push notification, you may don't want it to be received by non authorized app users.

**Android solution**

For Android it's easier.

As soon as you get a token on the server, just send a push message with some randomly generated string (store it in DB). Your application on a device will get this string and will send it with the token to the server (via second web call). And your server make sure that it will send anything to this token only after it was authenticated.

This way you rely on GCM ability to deliver messages to correct clients to make sure that authentication information (random string) is delivered to your application.

**iOS solution**

The problem with iOS is that push notification doesn't automatically trigger code execution, if the application is suspended or in background.

So, if you will try to do the same thing and a user accidentally exits your app, while push notification is being deliver than your app will never see it.

You can do following (the idea is basically the same as for Android, only with difference that we may need to require user interaction)

- Push notification with a message "Please run my app and enter X" (where X is some random string)
- This way, if your app is in background, a user will click on this message, enter X and your app will authenticated to the server.
- In the case, if app is in foreground, it will get push payload and can authenticate directly.